# AS3: Using string as variable

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a possibility to extract variable name from string and using it as variable

```
var myvar:String = "flash";
var flash:Number = 10;
trace( myvar as variable );
```

something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it as a property of an object.

```
public dynamic class MyClass {
    function MyClass(propName:String, propValue:*) {
        this[propName] = propValue;
    }
}
```

or

```
var myvar:String = "flash";
var o : Object = {};
o[myvar] = 10;
trace(o.flash); //10
```

If you don't know what property name is going to be, then you should use `dynamic` class (`Object` is `dynamic` by default)

Answer (score 6):

Variable name as Strings can be done like so:

```
this["myvar"] = "flash";
```

Notes:

- This will throw a `ReferenceError` if the property has not been previously defined AND the `this` refers to an object which is not `dynamic`.
- You can of course replace `this` with the instance name of an object you want to use a property from, e.g. `mySprite["x"]`.
- You can also use this approach to call methods: `this["addChild"](mySprite);`

Answer (score 1):

What you require is similar to the `Dictionary` class in .NET, and it is available by default in the `Object` class of AS3.

```
var key:String="hello";
var value:int=100;
var map:Object=new Object();
map[key]=value;
```

Now, you can get your stored value as

```
trace(map[key]);
```

If you want, you can also build on this to make a class like the following:

```
public class Dictionary {
    private var _keys:Array;
    private var _maps:Object;
    public function Dictionary() {
        _keys=[];
        _maps:Object={};
    }

    //Returns the array of all saved keys
    public function get keys():Array {
        return _keys;
    }

    //Sets a key-value pair
    public function setProperty(key:*, value:*):int {
        _maps[key]=value;
        return _keys.push(key);
    }

    //Returns the value stored at a particular key
    public function getProperty(key:*):* {
        if(_keys.indexOf(key) != -1) {
            return _maps[key];
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Removes a key-value pair if it exists and returns if the key existed
    public function deleteProperty(key:*):Boolean {
        var ix:int;
        if((ix=_keys.indexOf(key)) != -1) {
            //dissociate value from key
            delete _maps[key];
            //delete key
            _keys.splice[ix,1];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can use this as:

```
var dict:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
//set the value
dict.setProperty("flash", 10);

//get the value
dict.getProperty("flash");

//delete if not required
dict.deleteProperty("flash");
```

Note that this can be used to set keys and values of ANY type. Also it resolves the issue of the `ReferenceError` if the property is not defined, and you don't need to use any dynamic class in YOUR code (since the `Dictionary` class handles it internally).

One very typical use of this would be to define parse functions.
e.g. in a spreadsheet viewer:

```
var parseFuncts:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
parseFuncts.setProperty("csv", Parsers.parseCSV);
parseFuncts.setProperty("xml", Parsers.parseXML);
parseFuncts.setProperty("txt", Parsers.parseTXT);
parseFuncts.setProperty("xls", Parsers.parseXLS);
parseFuncts.setProperty("xlsx", Parsers.parseXLSX);

var fileToOpen:File; //Already contains the file to open

private function open():void {
    var f:Function=parseFuncts.getProperty(fileToOpen.extension);
    f.apply(this);
}
```

Comment: [AS3 has a `Dictionary` class.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html)

Comment: @MartyWallace, doh! Never looked for it, didn't know it existed. Thanks for letting me know :P